# Install GApps zip on Android device without recovery

Tags: android

I need help figuring out how to install a Google Apps .zip (or gapps package) on an Android device without using recovery. I have not seen this process documented anywhere, and before I go manually copying files from the zip onto a device, I'd like to see if anyone can give me some guidance. The device in question is rooted, but installing a custom recovery (such as Clockwork) is not an option. It seems straightforward enough (as the zip's internal file structure is recognizably an android fsh), but before I go and happily copy a bunch of files to a critical test device I'd like some input as to whether or not there is a preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late but i have done this yesterday because i have the same probleme.

The option i use is open a root shell with adb.
Then use the linux mount command 
I don't remember the exact command but it's look like this:
"mount -o remount,rw ext4 /system"
And then i copy the file of the system folder of the gapps zip to /system then i reboot my phone and all gapps were installed

Hope it help you or someone who found this like me in the futur.